# library for string comparison in python

Tags: python, string

I am looking for library or functions in python for string comparison. I want to have output as index positions with respect to fist string where it differs from other string in comparison. Mostly like `strcmp()` in language C.

eg.

```
String A='ABCD'
String B='ADCT'

print(compare(A,B))
```

Output:

```
1

3
```

As `String A` is different from `String B` at index positions 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a library but an easy way to do what you want:

```
string_a = 'ABCD'
string_b = 'ADCT'

print ([ind for ind,char in enumerate(string_a) if string_b[ind] != char])
[1, 3]
```

`enumerate` gives you the index of each char through the string, `if string_b[ind] != char` checks if the chars at corresponding indexes are not the same.

`string_b` will have to be the same length or shorter than `string_a` or you will get an `index error`.

`zip` will work for uneven length strings:

```
[ ind for ind, tup  in enumerate (zip(string_a,string_b)) if tup[0] != tup[1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.context_diff) module:

```
import difflib

if __name__ == "__main__":

    diff = difflib.ndiff('ABCD', 'ADCT')
    for item in diff:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
def compare(a, b, printAll=True):
   if len(a)!=len(b):
       return False
   diff = [i for i,char in enumerate(a) if b[i] != char]
   if printAll:
       for pos in diff:
           print(pos)
   else:
       return diff
```

So, then: `compare('ABCD', 'ABCT')`

Outputs:

```
1
3
```

and if then if you want a list, you use: `compare('ABCD', 'ABCT', printAll=False)`

Outputs:

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A='ABCD'
B='ADCT'

if len(A)==len(B):
        for i in [idx[0]+1 for idx in enumerate(A) if A[idx[0]]==B[idx[0]]]:
            print(str(i)+'\n')
```